# How to combine groups in Regex with non capturing groups to have all optional

Tags: regex

**What I'm trying to achieve**: I want to match user entered sentence with my templates and to see which template matches better (as many groups out of all in template as possible).

**Regex which I'm building to solve example**:

```
^(\bMyCompany1\b)?(?:.+)?\s(\bestablishes\b)?(?:.+)?\s(\bAnotherCompany\b)?(?:.+)?$
```

**Example sentences**:

- `'MyCompany1 establishes AnotherCompany'` - matches all 3 groups. is OK
- `'MyCompany1 establ AnotherCompany'` - matches first and last group. ignres the middle typo. is also Ok
- `'MyCompany1 establishes AnotherCompany    '`   - space in the end. cannot identify 2 and 3 groups. I don't understand why
- `'MyCompany1 establishes   AnotherCompany'` - additional spaces after word 'establishes'. For some reason is not detecting 2nd group anymore

This regex is just an example of one template. I will have 1 regex (build dynamically) per each template. Like 'User1 sent a request to User2', 'Company1 borrowed to Company2 $111' My idea is to define each part of the template and to see how many parts I matched. E.g. in my example: - I expect some company name from the list (MyCompany or MyCompany1) or non capturing group to ignore the rest (maybe user did a typo or is just typing and hasn't finished) - I expect same order of groups to be there

Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong in my Regex? Is it correct to achieve that by using Regex at all?

Comment: Do You want your regex to match all your examples?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to find with your regex?

Comment: I think you should NOT have all the keywords optional. I played with your problem and this is wat I noticed. Play [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/cGaWqp/1) to see yourself. I simplified the expression, and named the capture groups. The worst case scenario is when there is no keyword, but there is still a match.

Comment: Why have you revert the formating I have made? Your question is unreadable like that.

Comment: `\s` only matches one space. You should use `\s+` to match one or more.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details, hope it is more clear. In short - I want all captured groups to be optional (for case when user hasn't entered the entire sentence.. and just starts typing -> here I will match either nothing or first group.. and so on. )

Comment: I restored the formatting improvement that Toto did. Make sure to not destroy that again, John. BTW, no need to add "Thank you" at the end.

Comment: Is that what you want? https://regex101.com/r/WAVS6M/1

Comment: Toto, sorry, I was changing the description, that's why most probably destroyed the formatting. 
Regarding your solution, it is not exactly. It is not working for my 4th example. When I have more spaces between words or any additional word, like 'MyCompany1 establishes     AnotherCompany' or 'MyCompany1 establishes  today AnotherCompany'

Comment: Edited regex: https://regex101.com/r/WAVS6M/3

Comment: virolino, that is my main concern. Is it possible to achieve the goal using all them as optional. I described it above - I may have situation that user did mistakes or missed some part, that's why I want to compare the sentence using all templates and to find closest template

Comment: @Toto, yes, almost what I want. 2 cases which came to my mind and not working. 
  
'MyCompany1 today establishes AnotherCompany'
  
'MyCompany1 establishes AnotherCompany problem'
  
It cannot identify 2nd group in first example and 3rd in second. 
Can you give some hint how it works? I mean that for word 'today' is uses same part of regex '.+?' - but having same after first group is not catching that

Comment: I think this is working: https://regex101.com/r/WAVS6M/5

Comment: @Toto, can you please help with 2 more examples: 
'MyCompany1 establishes AnotherCompany something   '
'MyCompany1    today establishes     dfdfg AnotherCompany dfdf'

https://regex101.com/r/JJXtaq/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covering all your test cases, it is based on 3 lookaheads, each one contain an optional non-capture that includes a group for every keywords you're looking for.

```
^(?=(?:.*(\bMyCompany1\b))?)(?=(?:.*?(\bestablishes\b))?)(?=(?:.*(\bAnotherCompany\b))?).*$
```

You'll get regex explanation at the link below:

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JJXtaq/2)

Or, if the order matter:

```
^(?:.*(\bMyCompany1\b))?(?:.*?(\bestablishes\b))?(?:.*(\bAnotherCompany\b))?.*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JJXtaq/3)

Comment: One question here. Is it possible to force to follow the order? Currently, if I switch words it will also match: 'MyCompany1 AnotherCompany establishes'

Comment: @JohnConstantine: Just remove the lookaheads, see: https://regex101.com/r/JJXtaq/3

Answer (score 0):

could you please try below regex

> ^(\bMyCompany1\b)?\s+(\bestablishes\b)?\s+(\bAnotherCompany\b)?(?:.+)?$

hope it helps

Comment: Have you tried it? What about the second example: `'MyCompany1 establ AnotherCompany'` ?